# Redirect to URL using Regular Expressions in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

How to Redirect to URL using Regular Expressions in Fiddler?

> If URL mathes 
>   regex:(?insx)^http://www.(.*)$ 
>   respond to
>   http://proxy.exampleproxy.info/?u=(???? what wtite here ???)

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to redirect *to*?

Comment: I have the same problem—how do you get the captured match into the response.

Have tried `$1` and `${1}` but neither work.

Using `(?n)` at the start means you must use explicit capture groups.
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/help/AutoResponder.asp

which are explained:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(VS.80).aspx
and
http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

I was trying something like this:
`regex:(?n)^http://www.(?<foo>.*)$` and respond with:
`http://proxy.exampleproxy.info/?u=${foo}`

but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [AutoResponder](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/AutoResponder) tab to provide regex with [groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as *match rule* and use [substitution syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in *action string*.

For example write this in *match rule* input:

`regex:(?isx).*\.mycdn\.net\/.+\.(jpg|png)\?w=(\d+)&h=(\d+) #matching image urls from cdn`

and this in *action string* input:

`*redir:http://lorempixel.com/$2/$3/cats`

this rule will match url like this:

http://someimage.mycdn.net/some-directory/some-url.jpg?w=300&h=166

and would redirect to this url

http://lorempixel.com/300/166/cats/

`*redir` action means that fiddler would respond with 307 code (Temporary Redirect) and `Location` header with url to redirect. If you omit this string then fiddler would respond with 301 code (Moved Permanently) instead.

Answer (score 0):

fiddler2 doesn't support using the capture text in the response.
http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/msg/60e8b897867cdb7b

Need to use rules instead.